# facebook wall feeds output - access_token issue

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-wall

I've an apparently simple problem that is killing me. I read a lot on this topic but I cannot find any solution.

when I access to my wall with this url:

Profile feed (Wall): https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=(ACCESS_TOKEN GENERATED_BY_FACEBOOK),

I get all status feeds I've posted but if I use an access token generated by an app (that I own) I get feeds I've posted and comments I've posted to others posts on the same level.

how can I generate an app access token to obtain the same result as the facebook generated one?